# How to get column name using wpdb get_results dynamically

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress

This is my code snippet I want to get fields name like mysqli fetch_fields() to work. It returns column names from the query without explicitly defining each column name.

```
if (isset($_POST['sqlstmt']) && !empty($_POST['sqlstmt'])) {
    //$errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
    $sql = $_POST['sqlstmt'];
    $sql = stripslashes($sql);
    $result = $wpdadb->get_results($sql);
}
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#select-generic-results `get_results($sql, OBJECT_K)` gets you an associative array or call `get_col_info` to get all column info https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_col_info/

Comment: Ok thanks i try and let you know.

Comment: get_col_info works in my case. Thanks